# Why cant i select an <li> added via .append?

Tags: javascript, html

When i add an `<li>` with the css below i can select the item but if i add it using `.append` i cannot what am i doing wrong?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="events" class="select" name="events">
<li>Opt 1</li>
</ul>
```

.

```
$('ul.select li').click(function(e){
  var item = $(e.target);
  item.addClass('selected');
  item.siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $('#events').val(item.text());
});

$('#events').append('<li>Opt 2</li>');
```

.

```
ul.select {
   list-style: none;
   margin:  0;
   padding: 2px;
   height:50vh;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   border: 1px solid grey;
   width: 50vw;
   background-color: black;
   color: white
}

ul.select li {
   padding: 2px 6px;
}
ul.select li:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
}
ul.select li.selected {
   background-color: lightgrey;
   color: black;
}
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0086x0jf/) for example of issue.

Comment: Your link is broken

Comment: The event handler you set up doesn't extend into the future, it is only applied to elements that already exist. If you add new `<li>`s you have to set it up again. Just wrap it in a function and call that after appending.

Comment: @Lixus link now sorted - thanks for flagging

Comment: CSS Loads in when the page does, if you add elements dynamically, the CSS wont affect it

Comment: @RandomDeveloper 100% incorrect

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks - that is the issue, sorry for a simple question, very new to html and JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('ul.select li').click` will add an event listener to all elements, which match this selector, at the time of the code being called. The following will work:

```
$('.select').on('click', 'li', function(){
    // code here 
});
```

This is called event delegation. Essentially you add an event listener to an element higher up the chain (`.select`). The click event is then propegated up to the element higher up the chain (`.select`) and if `e.target` matches the selector (`li`), the callback is called.